# How to install KUDO Kubectl Plugin in linux without using brew?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, plugins, kubectl, minikube

I am new in creating Kubernetes operators and found we can easily make one using the **KUDO (Kubernetes Universal Declarative Operator)** plugin. From the documentation, KUDO was installed using `brew` https://kudo.dev/docs/cli.html#setup-the-kudo-kubectl-plugin. Can anyone suggest a method to setup KUDO in linux without using `linuxbrew-wrapper` ?

Comment: Hi, try this one first install krew `https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew/#installation then  ``kubectl krew install kudo``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround to fix the kudo plugin in linux reducing the overhead of installing brew.

```
 apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
 brew install kudo-cli
```

First you figure out the corresponding package from the [release](https://github.com/kudobuilder/kudo/releases) page, which is compatible to your machine. Download and extract the file (my case : `kudo_0.10.1_linux_x86_64.tar.gz`) and there you can find the executable for `kubectl-kudo`.

Export the path :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/downloaded/executable/
```

You are almost done and can find the commands working. Try `kubectl kudo version`.

To make it permanent add this export line into your `.bashrc` and reload.